# I'm the only female muslimah in medical school, can I have friends

Tags: friendship

I am the only female in my medical class. I don't want to have anything to do with the Kafirs but academically, I need to have friends to help me along the way. They see my hijjab as a problem and I don't know what to do.

Comment: As long as they’re not boys and as long as they’re not a bad influence upon yourself, you can have female friends.

Comment: @Epistemophile.Bibliophile I believe your answer is the perfect answer, concise and accurate, I guess you could elaborate on "not a bad influence" and post that as a legitimate answer

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi basically tempting you to abandon Islam/go against Islam, sin, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can find any position in Islam with respect to this, from the very conservative answer «A woman must not travel except with a mahram and a man must not enter upon her except if she has a mahram. So you cannot study in this place.» [1](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa-birmingham/19477) over a moderate conservative «you can join mixed gatherings as long as all people respect the given rules of Islam»[2](https://www.dar-alifta.org/Foreign/ViewFatwa.aspx?ID=9384&text=gender%20mixing) [3](https://hawramani.com/muslim-woman-going-to-a-mixed-university/) until a reform position «There is no interdiction of gender mixing in the quran. As long as you dress properly and do not seek a forbidden relationship, it is allowed» [4](http://www.quranicpath.com/misconceptions/lowering_gaze.html).

As the very conservative position is not an option for you anyway, you may opt for something close to the moderate position. You may study with a group of students who accept the rules you explain to them and whom you trust that they will do so, and you meet in a public place.

You co-students with whom you learn would be collegues rather than friends. As private friends, you can chose female friends you like.